# Sketch the graph $x=e^{-t}\sin t$,$ t\ge 0$

Tags: exponential-function, algebraic-curves

My graph is always negative though, and that doesn't make sense cause $t$ is supposed to be positive. 
I substituted $x$ as $y$ and $t$ as $x$.

Comment: Can you show us what you did? Maybe include a picture?

Comment: I'm not sure how to post a picture

Comment: Check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3De%5E%28-t%29sin+t+%2C+t%3E%3D0) out

Comment: Oh thanks! Btw, anyone knows how to get that graph on a graphic calculator?

Answer (score 1):

To draw this graph without the use of a graphics calculator or graphing software, first sketch the graphs of $x=e^{-t}$ and the reflection of this in the $t$ axis, $x=-e^{-t}$

Now sketch the graph of $x=\sin t$ so that it has the same roots as usual, but the amplitude **decreases** so that it fits between the two exponential graphs, only touching them when $\sin t=\pm1$.

Note that the stationary points are not the same points as where the diminishing sine wave and its exponential "envelopes" touch.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some portions of the graphs:

[image]

[image]

[image]